# How to stop download of a single image

Tags: android, android-activity, universal-image-loader

I'm creating an application where the user selects one item from a recycler view and this starts the download of a group of images.

I'm using `universal image loader's` **loadImage** method to fetch images for me which is working very well.

The problem is,if the user wants to cancel downloading this group of images (can be very network consuming) I cannot find a way to make ui stop only some of the images.

I'm aware of the method `ImageLoader.cancelDisplayTask()`, but as I'm using `loadImage` I have no `ImageView` or `ImageAware` available to send as a parameter to this task.

Also `ImageLoader.stop()` or `ImageLoader.pause()` stops all current downloads and I want to stop only the ones selected by the user.

How can I achieve this?

**PS:** A suggestion to some future development would be returning a pointer of the download task when using `loadImage` method. Maybe I'll look it myself when I have some time to contribute to this awesome library.

Here's my code for downloading an image.

```
private void downloadFile(final URL downloadURL,
                          final URL destinationURL,
                          final boolean isThumbnail,
                          final MyDownloadListener listener) {
    final NewsData thisClass = this;
    final ImageLoader il = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    File imageFile = il.getDiskCache().get(destinationURL.toString());
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
        fallDownloadCompleted(this, isThumbnail);
        return;
    }
    il.stop();
    il.loadImage(
            downloadURL.toString(),
            null,
            Application.getAppDisplayOptions(),
            new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onLoadingStarted(thisClass);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    fallDownloadFail(thisClass, failReason, isThumbnail);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    try {
                        il.getDiskCache().save(destinationURL.toString(), loadedImage);
                        if (isToday()) deleteImageFile(imageUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        deleteImageFile(imageUri);
                        fallDownloadFail(
                                thisClass,
                                new FailReason(FailReason.FailType.IO_ERROR, new Throwable()),
                                isThumbnail);
                        return;
                    }

                    fallDownloadCompleted(thisClass, isThumbnail);
                }
            },
            new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                    float progress = 0;
                    if (total > 0 && numberOfTotalPages > 0) {
                        if (!isThumbnail) {

                            progress = numberOfAvailablePages / (float) numberOfTotalPages;
                            progress += (current / (float) total) / numberOfTotalPages;

                        } else {
                            progress = current / (float) total;
                        }
                    }
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onProgressUpdate(thisClass, progress);

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code! Minimum the handler code for the ui event to start download, the datamodel used and the implementation of the async task/runable/etc which is doing the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue with a small workaround.

I couldn't find a way to cancel a particular `ImageLoader.loadImage()` so what I had to do was use the normal `ImageLoader.displayImage()` by passing a `NonViewAware` class in place of the image view required as a parameter.

I then added this `NonViewAware` into an `ArrayList<NonViewAware>` to keep track of which images were being downloaded.

Finally when I wanted to cancel a display task I just called `ImageLoader.cancelDisplayTask(NonViewAware)` with one of the stored items from the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList<ImageLoader> images = new ArrayList<ImageLoader>();

images.remove():
```

? Not familiar with ImageLoader class but I hope this helps

These might help

[android: Universal Image Loader get drawable from string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745238/android-universal-image-loader-get-drawable-from-string-array)

[How to change array list to string array for using Universal Image Loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841213/how-to-change-array-list-to-string-array-for-using-universal-image-loader)

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/109